# extract content from result after post with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm new with JQuery and I don't know how to do the next thing:

I'm doing a post to a remote website and it returns the whole page.
From the returned data I'm trying to extract divs with the next classes (error, and error_p).

So this is what I got:

```
var request = post(url);
request.done(function(data) {
   var errors;
   $("div").each(function(index, data) {
      if ($(this).attr("class") == "error" || $(this).attr("class") == "error_p")
         errors= errors+ $(this).val();
      });
}
```

The post works and I get the data, but the each loop is wrong.

The first thing I'm not sure is how to loop over the content of data extracting the divs, and second, once that I have all those divs, how to extract their values if their classes match with the ones I said before.

Thanks!

Comment: What is `data` like? Some html / response please...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var $divs = []; // make an array.
 $("div", data).each(function(index, data) {// loop

     if ($(this).hasClass("error") || $(this).hasClass("error_p"));
     // use hasClass method. A div can have more than one class.

$divs.push($(this));// save the reference.

for (var i = 0, len = $divs.length; i < len; i++) {
    console.log($divs[i].html());
};
```

Comment: Hello alex23, thanks for your fast answer. I tried your code, but it is filtering the HTML where I'm executing that script, and not the HTML in the variable data.

Comment: I solved it editing the second line: $("div", data).each(function(index, data)